# How to remove or disable a menu item from a JPopupMenu?

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem, jpopupmenu, abstract-action

I have a `JPopupMenu` and I want to disable or remove, if possible, a menu item every time an action happens. So I tried this, and though the `removeCommentAction` object is added in the position 4 of the menu, the menu item in position 4 is not removed.
I know about the menu item method setEnabled but how can this be implemented in this case with the `AbstractAction` object?

```
        nodeMenu.remove(4);
        nodeMenu.insert(new RemoveCommentAction(),4)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of removing/adding, add them all, keep references and disable the `Action` as needed.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: MenuItem removeItem=new RemoveCommentAction()?